# How to set Cache-Control header for external js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, cache-control

PageSpeed suggested that I add Cache-Control headers for some external js (from adsense).

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching

How do I do that for a ASP.net Website? I have done it for local resources by adding a web.config for the js folder.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to have a local copy of the script. You could program something (maybe in `Global.asax`'s `BeginRequest` method?) that would refresh this local copy once in a while.